# Professor what is it?

Tags: single-word-requests

**Email:**
Dr. Elbert Ainstein,
*Dear sir I have read everything you ever wrote. blah blah.. Your paper on so..more blah... I wish to study at your esteemed blahblahb....*
Yours Sincerely,
Beststud Youlleverhave

Dr. Elbert Ainstein is a professor and Beststud Youlleverhave is a student. Students often write mails to profs before admissions(to get admissions). I have been to a University's webpage. It said we encourage `Professor ________ing`.

I can't remember what that word was. What is it? What is the word for this thing?

Comment: The question is closed, but I suspect the word might have been COURTING. "To endeavor to gain the favor of by attention or flattery; to try to ingratiate one's self with."

Comment: What was the name of the university? You may be able to uncover the page again by doing a site-specific Google search with a quoted search term, i.e. `site:someuniversity.edu "we encourage professor"`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for the term 'brown-nosing.'

This is a synonym for 'sucking up to' or 'kissing ass.'

The purpose of such actions would be to gain the favor of a professor in order to influence their decision to admit you into their program.

Comment: I wish I knew a good source to link to.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "hey stop bringing the teacher apples every day y' brown nose!!"

Answer (score 0):

The general word could be "contacting"; a more specific word for what you are doing is "cold-calling". The concept of aid or assistance via a person is known as a "reference" which *could* have an associated "referencing".

Comment: No. It was something else.

Comment: Was it supplicating?

Comment: No. It was really cool word and probably began with "B". Damn!

Comment: Maybe "vetting"?